# Unicode ZPL example UTF8 ZPL

Tags: unicode, utf-8, zpl

I have created the following ZPL that is working when pasted into Labelary, but not working when printed (GK420D) via the `Zebra Setup Utilities` application.

I've tried this on a number of different devices, that have all been Factory Reset using the `Zebra Setup Utilities` application.

I would like a solution that doesn't need any additional fonts installing.

The ZPL I am using is as follows;

```
^XA
^CI28
^A0,28^FT0,30 ^FH^FD!^FS
^A0,28^FT0,60 ^FH^FD"^FS
^A0,28^FT0,90 ^FH^FD#^FS
^A0,28^FT0,120 ^FH^FD$^FS
^A0,28^FT0,150 ^FH^FD%^FS
^A0,28^FT0,180 ^FH^FD&^FS
^A0,28^FT0,210 ^FH^FD'^FS
^A0,28^FT0,240 ^FH^FD(^FS
^A0,28^FT0,270 ^FH^FD)^FS
^A0,28^FT0,300 ^FH^FD*^FS
^A0,28^FT0,330 ^FH^FD+^FS
^A0,28^FT0,360 ^FH^FD,^FS
^A0,28^FT0,390 ^FH^FD-^FS
^A0,28^FT0,420 ^FH^FD.^FS
^A0,28^FT0,450 ^FH^FD/^FS
^A0,28^FT0,480 ^FH^FD0^FS
^A0,28^FT0,510 ^FH^FD1^FS
^A0,28^FT0,540 ^FH^FD2^FS
^A0,28^FT0,570 ^FH^FD3^FS
^A0,28^FT0,600 ^FH^FD4^FS
^A0,28^FT30,30 ^FH^FD5^FS
^A0,28^FT30,60 ^FH^FD6^FS
^A0,28^FT30,90 ^FH^FD7^FS
^A0,28^FT30,120 ^FH^FD8^FS
^A0,28^FT30,150 ^FH^FD9^FS
^A0,28^FT30,180 ^FH^FD:^FS
^A0,28^FT30,210 ^FH^FD;^FS
^A0,28^FT30,240 ^FH^FD< ^FS
^A0,28^FT30,270 ^FH^FD=^FS
^A0,28^FT30,300 ^FH^FD> ^FS
^A0,28^FT30,330 ^FH^FD?^FS
^A0,28^FT30,360 ^FH^FD@^FS
^A0,28^FT30,390 ^FH^FDA^FS
^A0,28^FT30,420 ^FH^FDB^FS
^A0,28^FT30,450 ^FH^FDC^FS
^A0,28^FT30,480 ^FH^FDD^FS
^A0,28^FT30,510 ^FH^FDE^FS
^A0,28^FT30,540 ^FH^FDF^FS
^A0,28^FT30,570 ^FH^FDG^FS
^A0,28^FT30,600 ^FH^FDH^FS
^A0,28^FT60,30 ^FH^FDI^FS
^A0,28^FT60,60 ^FH^FDJ^FS
^A0,28^FT60,90 ^FH^FDK^FS
^A0,28^FT60,120 ^FH^FDL^FS
^A0,28^FT60,150 ^FH^FDM^FS
^A0,28^FT60,180 ^FH^FDN^FS
^A0,28^FT60,210 ^FH^FDO^FS
^A0,28^FT60,240 ^FH^FDP^FS
^A0,28^FT60,270 ^FH^FDQ^FS
^A0,28^FT60,300 ^FH^FDR^FS
^A0,28^FT60,330 ^FH^FDS^FS
^A0,28^FT60,360 ^FH^FDT^FS
^A0,28^FT60,390 ^FH^FDU^FS
^A0,28^FT60,420 ^FH^FDV^FS
^A0,28^FT60,450 ^FH^FDW^FS
^A0,28^FT60,480 ^FH^FDX^FS
^A0,28^FT60,510 ^FH^FDY^FS
^A0,28^FT60,540 ^FH^FDZ^FS
^A0,28^FT60,570 ^FH^FD[^FS
^A0,28^FT60,600 ^FH^FD\^FS
^A0,28^FT90,30 ^FH^FD]^FS
^A0,28^FT90,60 ^FH^FD^^FS
^A0,28^FT90,90 ^FH^FD_^FS
^A0,28^FT90,120 ^FH^FD`^FS
^A0,28^FT90,150 ^FH^FDa^FS
^A0,28^FT90,180 ^FH^FDb^FS
^A0,28^FT90,210 ^FH^FDc^FS
^A0,28^FT90,240 ^FH^FDd^FS
^A0,28^FT90,270 ^FH^FDe^FS
^A0,28^FT90,300 ^FH^FDf^FS
^A0,28^FT90,330 ^FH^FDg^FS
^A0,28^FT90,360 ^FH^FDh^FS
^A0,28^FT90,390 ^FH^FDi^FS
^A0,28^FT90,420 ^FH^FDj^FS
^A0,28^FT90,450 ^FH^FDk^FS
^A0,28^FT90,480 ^FH^FDl^FS
^A0,28^FT90,510 ^FH^FDm^FS
^A0,28^FT90,540 ^FH^FDn^FS
^A0,28^FT90,570 ^FH^FDo^FS
^A0,28^FT90,600 ^FH^FDp^FS
^A0,28^FT120,30 ^FH^FDq^FS
^A0,28^FT120,60 ^FH^FDr^FS
^A0,28^FT120,90 ^FH^FDs^FS
^A0,28^FT120,120 ^FH^FDt^FS
^A0,28^FT120,150 ^FH^FDu^FS
^A0,28^FT120,180 ^FH^FDv^FS
^A0,28^FT120,210 ^FH^FDw^FS
^A0,28^FT120,240 ^FH^FDx^FS
^A0,28^FT120,270 ^FH^FDy^FS
^A0,28^FT120,300 ^FH^FDz^FS
^A0,28^FT120,330 ^FH^FD{^FS
^A0,28^FT120,360 ^FH^FD|^FS
^A0,28^FT120,390 ^FH^FD}^FS
^A0,28^FT120,420 ^FH^FD~^FS
^A0,28^FT120,450 ^FH^FD¡^FS
^A0,28^FT120,480 ^FH^FD¢^FS
^A0,28^FT120,510 ^FH^FD£^FS
^A0,28^FT120,540 ^FH^FD¤^FS
^A0,28^FT120,570 ^FH^FD¥^FS
^A0,28^FT120,600 ^FH^FD¦^FS
^A0,28^FT150,30 ^FH^FD§^FS
^A0,28^FT150,60 ^FH^FD¨^FS
^A0,28^FT150,90 ^FH^FD©^FS
^A0,28^FT150,120 ^FH^FDª^FS
^A0,28^FT150,150 ^FH^FD«^FS
^A0,28^FT150,180 ^FH^FD¬^FS
^A0,28^FT150,210 ^FH^FD^FS
^A0,28^FT150,240 ^FH^FD®^FS
^A0,28^FT150,270 ^FH^FD¯^FS
^A0,28^FT150,300 ^FH^FD°^FS
^A0,28^FT150,330 ^FH^FD±^FS
^A0,28^FT150,360 ^FH^FD²^FS
^A0,28^FT150,390 ^FH^FD³^FS
^A0,28^FT150,420 ^FH^FD´^FS
^A0,28^FT150,450 ^FH^FDµ^FS
^A0,28^FT150,480 ^FH^FD¶^FS
^A0,28^FT150,510 ^FH^FD·^FS
^A0,28^FT150,540 ^FH^FD¸^FS
^A0,28^FT150,570 ^FH^FD¹^FS
^A0,28^FT150,600 ^FH^FDº^FS
^A0,28^FT180,30 ^FH^FD»^FS
^A0,28^FT180,60 ^FH^FD¼^FS
^A0,28^FT180,90 ^FH^FD½^FS
^A0,28^FT180,120 ^FH^FD¾^FS
^A0,28^FT180,150 ^FH^FD¿^FS
^A0,28^FT180,180 ^FH^FDÀ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,210 ^FH^FDÁ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,240 ^FH^FDÂ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,270 ^FH^FDÃ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,300 ^FH^FDÄ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,330 ^FH^FDÅ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,360 ^FH^FDÆ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,390 ^FH^FDÇ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,420 ^FH^FDÈ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,450 ^FH^FDÉ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,480 ^FH^FDÊ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,510 ^FH^FDË^FS
^A0,28^FT180,540 ^FH^FDÌ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,570 ^FH^FDÍ^FS
^A0,28^FT180,600 ^FH^FDÎ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,30 ^FH^FDÏ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,60 ^FH^FDÐ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,90 ^FH^FDÑ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,120 ^FH^FDÒ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,150 ^FH^FDÓ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,180 ^FH^FDÔ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,210 ^FH^FDÕ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,240 ^FH^FDÖ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,270 ^FH^FD×^FS
^A0,28^FT210,300 ^FH^FDØ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,330 ^FH^FDÙ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,360 ^FH^FDÚ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,390 ^FH^FDÛ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,420 ^FH^FDÜ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,450 ^FH^FDÝ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,480 ^FH^FDÞ^FS
^A0,28^FT210,510 ^FH^FDß^FS
^A0,28^FT210,540 ^FH^FDà^FS
^A0,28^FT210,570 ^FH^FDá^FS
^A0,28^FT210,600 ^FH^FDâ^FS
^A0,28^FT240,30 ^FH^FDã^FS
^A0,28^FT240,60 ^FH^FDä^FS
^A0,28^FT240,90 ^FH^FDå^FS
^A0,28^FT240,120 ^FH^FDæ^FS
^A0,28^FT240,150 ^FH^FDç^FS
^A0,28^FT240,180 ^FH^FDè^FS
^A0,28^FT240,210 ^FH^FDé^FS
^A0,28^FT240,240 ^FH^FDê^FS
^A0,28^FT240,270 ^FH^FDë^FS
^A0,28^FT240,300 ^FH^FDì^FS
^A0,28^FT240,330 ^FH^FDí^FS
^A0,28^FT240,360 ^FH^FDî^FS
^A0,28^FT240,390 ^FH^FDï^FS
^A0,28^FT240,420 ^FH^FDð^FS
^A0,28^FT240,450 ^FH^FDñ^FS
^A0,28^FT240,480 ^FH^FDò^FS
^A0,28^FT240,510 ^FH^FDó^FS
^A0,28^FT240,540 ^FH^FDô^FS
^A0,28^FT240,570 ^FH^FDõ^FS
^A0,28^FT240,600 ^FH^FDö^FS
^A0,28^FT270,30 ^FH^FD÷^FS
^A0,28^FT270,60 ^FH^FDø^FS
^A0,28^FT270,90 ^FH^FDù^FS
^A0,28^FT270,120 ^FH^FDú^FS
^A0,28^FT270,150 ^FH^FDû^FS
^A0,28^FT270,180 ^FH^FDü^FS
^A0,28^FT270,210 ^FH^FDý^FS
^A0,28^FT270,240 ^FH^FDþ^FS
^A0,28^FT270,270 ^FH^FDÿ^FS
^XZ
```

I have also tried using HEX encoding with the "embedded swiss font";

```
^XA
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT30,30 ^FH^FD_21^FS
^FT30,60 ^FH^FD_22^FS
^FT30,90 ^FH^FD_23^FS
^FT30,120 ^FH^FD_24^FS
^FT30,150 ^FH^FD_25^FS
^FT30,180 ^FH^FD_26^FS
^FT30,210 ^FH^FD_27^FS
^FT30,240 ^FH^FD_28^FS
^FT30,270 ^FH^FD_29^FS
^FT30,300 ^FH^FD_2A^FS
^FT30,330 ^FH^FD_2B^FS
^FT30,360 ^FH^FD_2C^FS
^FT30,390 ^FH^FD_2D^FS
^FT30,420 ^FH^FD_2E^FS
^FT30,450 ^FH^FD_2F^FS
^FT30,480 ^FH^FD_30^FS
^FT30,510 ^FH^FD_31^FS
^FT30,540 ^FH^FD_32^FS
^FT30,570 ^FH^FD_33^FS
^FT30,600 ^FH^FD_34^FS
^FT60,30 ^FH^FD_35^FS
^FT60,60 ^FH^FD_36^FS
^FT60,90 ^FH^FD_37^FS
^FT60,120 ^FH^FD_38^FS
^FT60,150 ^FH^FD_39^FS
^FT60,180 ^FH^FD_3A^FS
^FT60,210 ^FH^FD_3B^FS
^FT60,240 ^FH^FD_3C^FS
^FT60,270 ^FH^FD_3D^FS
^FT60,300 ^FH^FD_3E^FS
^FT60,330 ^FH^FD_3F^FS
^FT60,360 ^FH^FD_40^FS
^FT60,390 ^FH^FD_41^FS
^FT60,420 ^FH^FD_42^FS
^FT60,450 ^FH^FD_43^FS
^FT60,480 ^FH^FD_44^FS
^FT60,510 ^FH^FD_45^FS
^FT60,540 ^FH^FD_46^FS
^FT60,570 ^FH^FD_47^FS
^FT60,600 ^FH^FD_48^FS
^FT90,30 ^FH^FD_49^FS
^FT90,60 ^FH^FD_4A^FS
^FT90,90 ^FH^FD_4B^FS
^FT90,120 ^FH^FD_4C^FS
^FT90,150 ^FH^FD_4D^FS
^FT90,180 ^FH^FD_4E^FS
^FT90,210 ^FH^FD_4F^FS
^FT90,240 ^FH^FD_50^FS
^FT90,270 ^FH^FD_51^FS
^FT90,300 ^FH^FD_52^FS
^FT90,330 ^FH^FD_53^FS
^FT90,360 ^FH^FD_54^FS
^FT90,390 ^FH^FD_55^FS
^FT90,420 ^FH^FD_56^FS
^FT90,450 ^FH^FD_57^FS
^FT90,480 ^FH^FD_58^FS
^FT90,510 ^FH^FD_59^FS
^FT90,540 ^FH^FD_5A^FS
^FT90,570 ^FH^FD_5B^FS
^FT90,600 ^FH^FD_5C^FS
^FT120,30 ^FH^FD_5D^FS
^FT120,60 ^FH^FD_5E^FS
^FT120,90 ^FH^FD_5F^FS
^FT120,120 ^FH^FD_60^FS
^FT120,150 ^FH^FD_61^FS
^FT120,180 ^FH^FD_62^FS
^FT120,210 ^FH^FD_63^FS
^FT120,240 ^FH^FD_64^FS
^FT120,270 ^FH^FD_65^FS
^FT120,300 ^FH^FD_66^FS
^FT120,330 ^FH^FD_67^FS
^FT120,360 ^FH^FD_68^FS
^FT120,390 ^FH^FD_69^FS
^FT120,420 ^FH^FD_6A^FS
^FT120,450 ^FH^FD_6B^FS
^FT120,480 ^FH^FD_6C^FS
^FT120,510 ^FH^FD_6D^FS
^FT120,540 ^FH^FD_6E^FS
^FT120,570 ^FH^FD_6F^FS
^FT120,600 ^FH^FD_70^FS
^FT150,30 ^FH^FD_71^FS
^FT150,60 ^FH^FD_72^FS
^FT150,90 ^FH^FD_73^FS
^FT150,120 ^FH^FD_74^FS
^FT150,150 ^FH^FD_75^FS
^FT150,180 ^FH^FD_76^FS
^FT150,210 ^FH^FD_77^FS
^FT150,240 ^FH^FD_78^FS
^FT150,270 ^FH^FD_79^FS
^FT150,300 ^FH^FD_7A^FS
^FT150,330 ^FH^FD_7B^FS
^FT150,360 ^FH^FD_7C^FS
^FT150,390 ^FH^FD_7D^FS
^FT150,420 ^FH^FD_7E^FS
^FT150,450 ^FH^FD_A1^FS
^FT150,480 ^FH^FD_A2^FS
^FT150,510 ^FH^FD_A3^FS
^FT150,540 ^FH^FD_A4^FS
^FT150,570 ^FH^FD_A5^FS
^FT150,600 ^FH^FD_A6^FS
^FT180,30 ^FH^FD_A7^FS
^FT180,60 ^FH^FD_A8^FS
^FT180,90 ^FH^FD_A9^FS
^FT180,120 ^FH^FD_AA^FS
^FT180,150 ^FH^FD_AB^FS
^FT180,180 ^FH^FD_AC^FS
^FT180,210 ^FH^FD_20^FS
^FT180,240 ^FH^FD_AE^FS
^FT180,270 ^FH^FD_AF^FS
^FT180,300 ^FH^FD_B0^FS
^FT180,330 ^FH^FD_B1^FS
^FT180,360 ^FH^FD_B2^FS
^FT180,390 ^FH^FD_B3^FS
^FT180,420 ^FH^FD_B4^FS
^FT180,450 ^FH^FD_B5^FS
^FT180,480 ^FH^FD_B6^FS
^FT180,510 ^FH^FD_B7^FS
^FT180,540 ^FH^FD_B8^FS
^FT180,570 ^FH^FD_B9^FS
^FT180,600 ^FH^FD_BA^FS
^FT210,30 ^FH^FD_BB^FS
^FT210,60 ^FH^FD_BC^FS
^FT210,90 ^FH^FD_BD^FS
^FT210,120 ^FH^FD_BE^FS
^FT210,150 ^FH^FD_BF^FS
^FT210,180 ^FH^FD_C0^FS
^FT210,210 ^FH^FD_C1^FS
^FT210,240 ^FH^FD_C2^FS
^FT210,270 ^FH^FD_C3^FS
^FT210,300 ^FH^FD_C4^FS
^FT210,330 ^FH^FD_C5^FS
^FT210,360 ^FH^FD_C6^FS
^FT210,390 ^FH^FD_C7^FS
^FT210,420 ^FH^FD_C8^FS
^FT210,450 ^FH^FD_C9^FS
^FT210,480 ^FH^FD_CA^FS
^FT210,510 ^FH^FD_CB^FS
^FT210,540 ^FH^FD_CC^FS
^FT210,570 ^FH^FD_CD^FS
^FT210,600 ^FH^FD_CE^FS
^FT240,30 ^FH^FD_CF^FS
^FT240,60 ^FH^FD_D0^FS
^FT240,90 ^FH^FD_D1^FS
^FT240,120 ^FH^FD_D2^FS
^FT240,150 ^FH^FD_D3^FS
^FT240,180 ^FH^FD_D4^FS
^FT240,210 ^FH^FD_D5^FS
^FT240,240 ^FH^FD_D6^FS
^FT240,270 ^FH^FD_D7^FS
^FT240,300 ^FH^FD_D8^FS
^FT240,330 ^FH^FD_D9^FS
^FT240,360 ^FH^FD_DA^FS
^FT240,390 ^FH^FD_DB^FS
^FT240,420 ^FH^FD_DC^FS
^FT240,450 ^FH^FD_DD^FS
^FT240,480 ^FH^FD_DE^FS
^FT240,510 ^FH^FD_DF^FS
^FT240,540 ^FH^FD_E0^FS
^FT240,570 ^FH^FD_E1^FS
^FT240,600 ^FH^FD_E2^FS
^FT270,30 ^FH^FD_E3^FS
^FT270,60 ^FH^FD_E4^FS
^FT270,90 ^FH^FD_E5^FS
^FT270,120 ^FH^FD_E6^FS
^FT270,150 ^FH^FD_E7^FS
^FT270,180 ^FH^FD_E8^FS
^FT270,210 ^FH^FD_E9^FS
^FT270,240 ^FH^FD_EA^FS
^FT270,270 ^FH^FD_EB^FS
^FT270,300 ^FH^FD_EC^FS
^FT270,330 ^FH^FD_ED^FS
^FT270,360 ^FH^FD_EE^FS
^FT270,390 ^FH^FD_EF^FS
^FT270,420 ^FH^FD_F0^FS
^FT270,450 ^FH^FD_F1^FS
^FT270,480 ^FH^FD_F2^FS
^FT270,510 ^FH^FD_F3^FS
^FT270,540 ^FH^FD_F4^FS
^FT270,570 ^FH^FD_F5^FS
^FT270,600 ^FH^FD_F6^FS
^FT300,30 ^FH^FD_F7^FS
^FT300,60 ^FH^FD_F8^FS
^FT300,90 ^FH^FD_F9^FS
^FT300,120 ^FH^FD_FA^FS
^FT300,150 ^FH^FD_FB^FS
^FT300,180 ^FH^FD_FC^FS
^FT300,210 ^FH^FD_FD^FS
^FT300,240 ^FH^FD_FE^FS
^FT300,270 ^FH^FD_FF^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in my case was to save the text as a UTF-8 file (Notepad++ makes this easy) and then within **Zebra Setup Utilities** use *file | load* instead of *copy | paste*

Comment: So you didn't have to do ^CI28 nor hex encode (with ^FH^FD.. ASCII characters only need ^FD) nor the "swiss font" solution?

Comment: Nope, it was just the way the file was loaded into the setup app.

Comment: Thanks. I did those anyway. So it becomes independent of file's encoding.